# .net core azure WebJob 3.0.3 UseTimers missing

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk, azure-webjobs-triggered

I'm attempting to setup a new webjob using .net core 2.1 and I'm running into an issue where `UseTimers()` appears to be missing when I try to configure the job.

For the life of me I can't seem to find anything that will point me in the right direction as the documentation doesn't appear to be updated to reflect using `HostBuilder` instead of `JobHostConfiguration`.

I've even tried looking into the source for the WebJobs extensions but I can't seem to find anything to help and I'm at a loss now.

I've got the following which is fairly boilerplate  but this only works when I don't include `.UseTimers()`

```
using System.Threading.Tasks; 
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration; 
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting; 
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging; 
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs; 
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions;

namespace marqueone.webjob 
{
    class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {

            var builder = new HostBuilder()
            .UseEnvironment("Development")
            .ConfigureWebJobs(b =>
            {
                b.AddAzureStorageCoreServices()
                .AddAzureStorage();
            })
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration(b =>
            {
                b.AddCommandLine(args);
            })
            .ConfigureLogging((context, b) =>
            {
                b.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.Debug);
                b.AddConsole();
            })
            //.UseTimers()
            .UseConsoleLifetime();

            var host = builder.Build();
            using (host)
            {
                await host.RunAsync();
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per this [link](https://hajekj.net/2018/10/08/upgrading-to-webjobs-sdk-3-0/), you should use .AddTimers(), Like the following code:

```
.ConfigureWebJobs(config =>
{
    config.AddAzureStorageCoreServices();
    config.AddTimers();
})
```

And also in this [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/1871#issuecomment-432347037), it explain that:

```
 in general all the previous config.UseXXX extension methods migrated to 

IHostBuilder builder.AddXXX methods.
```